# Alternative CiviCRM theme

Tags: theme

I have looked a great bit into some alternatives to the default civicrm theme such as shoreditch, haystack, the CiviHR theme and one that agiliway developed for their demo site.

My question is what alternatives are most people using instead of their default civicrm theme? Custom theme or one of the alternatives i discussed above.

Answer (score 3):

We have been using [CiviCRM shoreditch theme](https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch) for quite a long time until we switched to [Kindly Theme](https://github.com/artfulrobot/aah) by [artfulrobot](https://github.com/artfulrobot) for some of our clients recently. Both are good in their own aspects. Around [2.4k](https://stats.civicrm.org/?tab=sites) sites in this universe are using [CiviCRM shoreditch theme](https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch). We also have custom theme inheriting Drupal bootstrap3 theme for some clients to match their screens.

Answer (score 0):

We use Shoreditch for most of our customers, Haystack for 1 and have looked at (but not yet used) the Aah or Kindly theme by artfulrobot.

Comment: It would be good to know what people are doing, theme wise, on the latest version of Drupal (9).  Have been using Shoreditch but this is only supported at present on D7. I looked at the Aah (Kindly) theme and that is also not ready for D9 either

Comment: In the meantime we now use Finsbury (https://civicrm.org/extensions/finsbury-park-cross-cms-admin-theme) the most....

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'll take a look and revert with some comments